# Many to many jpa relationship creating duplicated data in entity with new IDs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, many-to-many

I have two jpa entities User + profile with many to many relationship like below :

User Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "t_user")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long Id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 14)
    private String siret;
    @Cascade({
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE,
            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST
    })
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "t_user_profile", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")})
    private Set<ProfileEntity> profiles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ressource_id")
    private RessourceEntity ressource;
}
```

and Profile entity :

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "t_profile")
public class ProfileEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "profile_id")
    private Long Id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Profiles profile;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "profiles")
    private Set<UserEntity> user = new HashSet<>();
}
```

The problem is when I send an http request contaning the same profiles with different users, I obtain new duplicated profiles records with new IDs in the Profile table in the database like below :
[image]

but the correct way is to add the informations ONLY in the joined table t_user_profile because profile already exists in profile table .
[image]

I tried cascade.All , persist and merge .... but the same result .
And if I remove cascade and i search for profile Id using findById and get the Id and insert... I got a problem when the profile is new and don't exist in DB and the problem is because I removed cascade ... So I want if the profile already exists , I want to add the relationship in the joined table ONLY.

Comment: What exactly are you saving? Take a look at the objects being passed to JPA - if the referenced ProfileEntity instances don't have IDs, they are new and will be inserted and so have IDs assigned as new rows. Identity is the ONLY way for JPA to distinguish data - so if you want the ProfileEntity.profile to be unique as a natural Primary key, either make it the ID or ensure you are querying for the instance that already has that profile string and use that instance as the reference in your other entities.

Comment: in case of existing profile (name =X) in DB , I want to save the new data (profile entity, resource entity and user ...) only in the joined table (user_profile) because Profile X already exists in DB

Comment: but what ARE you currently saving - what is in the REST request exactly? I suspect strongly that you are NOT maintaining and passing around the ID values for existing ProfileEntity instances, which is a problem with your application design. The ID is what identifies the row, not the profile string. Ie in the table where you are trying to show duplicate profiles, NONE of them are duplicates. You've designed your DB and model such that multiple ProfileEntity instances can use the  same profile string value - it is up to your app to ensure they are not duplicated.

Comment: Put another way, take a look at your JSON->Java->JPA conversions. What you have shown in your entities cannot be converted to/from JSON as is, and that is where your problem lies as you are likely stripping out the Identity from your entities. If you do that, you have to then do the work to look up your instances based on the profile string (or some other natural identifiers within the data) so that you know when the profileEntity exists and when it needs to be created - JPA needs to know what ID from the profile entity to use in your join table.

Comment: I resolved it by removing   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "profiles")
    private Set<UserEntity> user = new HashSet<>();  from profile entity and checking in UserEntity if profile exists so we get the id and profile name , if not we create a new profile.  Thank you for your help